# Why does stopping the tkinter mainloop while a callback is queued cause an error in interactive mode?

Tags: python, tkinter, mainloop

Here's a piece of code that queues a callback with `Tk.after` and then destroys the window before the callback can be executed:

```
import tkinter as tk

win = tk.Tk()

win.after(0, win.destroy)
win.after(200, lambda: None)

win.mainloop()
```

Running this code normally produces no output:

```
Aran-Fey@DESKTOP-SJGQDQ8 /d/U/A/Desktop> python3 tkinter_demo.py
Aran-Fey@DESKTOP-SJGQDQ8 /d/U/A/Desktop>
```

But if the interpreter enters interactive mode after executing this code, tkinter prints an error message:

```
Aran-Fey@DESKTOP-SJGQDQ8 /d/U/A/Desktop> python3 -i tkinter_demo.py
>>> invalid command name "2256505886152<lambda>"
    while executing
"2256505886152<lambda>"
    ("after" script)
can't invoke "event" command: application has been destroyed
    while executing
"event generate $w <<ThemeChanged>>"
    (procedure "ttk::ThemeChanged" line 6)
    invoked from within
"ttk::ThemeChanged"
```

Why is this happening and what can I do about it?

Comment: Could not reproduce your issue. Try without `win.quit()` or as workaround `.after_cancel(...`. Verify with `print(win.protocol())`, `WM_DELETE_WINDOW` are set already. Relevant [destroy-vs-quit-not-working-as-intended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26086486/python-tkinter-toplevel-destroy-vs-quit-not-working-as-intended)

Comment: @stovfl Removing `win.quit()` has no effect. `WM_DELETE_WINDOW` is set per default, yes, but if I remove my custom `quit` function the problem still exists. `after_cancel` gets rid of the error message, but it's weird that `win.quit()` and `win.destroy()` don't cancel the queued callback automatically. I'd like to understand why that is. (Having to keep track of all queued callbacks and cancelling them manually before shutting down the mainloop is something I'd rather not have to do.)

Comment: ***"has no effect"***: Running the example as shown? Show your versions, OS, Python, tkinter, tcl

Comment: @stovfl Yes, running the example but without the `win.quit`. Windows 10 64bit, python 3.7.2, tkinter 8.6, tcl 8.6. More importantly though, I noticed the error is only displayed if the interpreter enters interactive mode after executing the script (`py -i script.py`).

Comment: ***"py -i script.py"***: Using `-i` i can reproduce the behavior. **Interactive** means a `tkinter` interpreter and therefore a `.mainloop` keeps running. I can offer you a **general** `.after_cancel(...` which does not need to keep track of the `aid = after(...`.

Comment: The error in `ttk::ThemeChanged` is due to a Tk bug (which your example code probably triggers fairly reliably: https://core.tcl-lang.org/tk/info/310c74ecf440). But that seems unrelated to the `invalid command name "2256505886152<lambda>"` error.